# Saving project as a template for future projects in visual studio express 2012?

Tags: windows-8, templates, visual-studio-2012

I have created my own project start up template that I would like to use for most of my future projects building Windows 8 apps with Visual Studio Express 2012.

I have looked online but cannot find any such documentation as to how I would take my existing project as is, and add it to the template list that is available when creating a new project.

Is this possible and how is it done?

I have tried simply opening the project and saving as a new project but the option does not exist for saving as a new project (do not know if it is because I only have Express?)

Answer (score 0):

Saving as template:

- Click export template in the file menu
- Choose project template
- Give it a name in the next page (`templatecardgame` or somthing)

Loading the template:

- Open project in the file menu
- Select the language in which you made the template
- In the middle screen is your template select it and give it a name

That's all and maybe a little late answer.